# carbon return number of days for a given year

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

Can Carbon return number of days for a given year?

```
    $dt = Carbon::parse($year . '-'. 1 .'-' . $from);

    var_dump($dt->format('z') + 1 );
```

this does not seems to work

Comment: What do you mean: The total number of days a year has, or the number of days passed in the year for a given date? 'z' lets me assume the latter, the question suggests the former...

Comment: Also: Why don't you use create(), instaed of parse(), if you have the int-values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo 'Days in the year: ', 365 + $dt->format('L');
```

> `L`: Whether it's a leap year; `1` if it is a leap year, `0` otherwise

Answer (score 3):

You can get by using carbon property

```
Carbon::parse('2020-01')->daysInYear //for year

Carbon::parse('2020-01')->daysInMonth //for month
```

Comment: yours should be the best answer ^_^    ....  ....  `now()->daysInYear`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a [comparison](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

```
echo 'Days in the year: ', ($dt->isLeapYear() ? 366 : 365);
```